# Adding a stroke to specific edges on SVG polygon

Tags: html, svg

I'm trying to create a custom map marker shape using SVG (created in JS, but for the sake of simplicity I've used the actual HTML here).
In this case, I've simply used a `circle` and a `polygon` element together to give the effect of a marker, below:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="30" width="30">
    <circle cx="15" cy="13" r="10" fill="#abcdef" />
    <polygon points="5,15 25,15 15,30" fill="#abcdef" />
</svg>
```

This is all well and good. However, I'd like to have a border around the outside of the shape, but if I try to add a stroke to the triangle, which forms the arrow of the marker, I get the line cutting through the circle, as shown:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="30" width="30">
    <circle cx="15" cy="13" r="10" fill="#abcdef" stroke="#595959" stroke-width="1" />
    <polygon points="5,15 25,15 15,30" fill="#abcdef" stroke="#595959" stroke-width="1" />
</svg>
```

I know there are probably many ways to achieve this effect, such as using the `path` tag, but my SVG knowledge isn't up to that level as of yet. Any pointers are appreciated.

Comment: @Sirko, please read the last sentence in the question.

Comment: Raise your SVG knowledge to the point you can use a path tag. Or use an SVG editor such as inkscape to create the path shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<path>` was my first idea. But while fiddling with the arc I got an even simpler idea:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="30" width="30">
    <circle cx="15" cy="13" r="11" fill="#595959" stroke="none"/>
    <polygon points="5,16 25,16 15,30" fill="#595959" stroke="none"/>
    <circle cx="15" cy="13" r="10" fill="#abcdef" stroke="none" />
    <polygon points="6,15 24,15 15,28" fill="#abcdef" stroke="none"/>
</svg>
```

...using `<circle>` and `polygon` twice, and with filling only.

The first set is for the border – hence a little bit larger.
The first set is covered by the second set for the actual filling.

Comment: Good idea, didn't think to duplicate the shapes.